# Is there a command to get the maximum folder depth of entire system?

Tags: macos, command-line

**Short version:** Is there a command and/or set of commands and/or utility to know what is the maximum depth of folders on my filesystem ?

**Long version:** I'm on Mac OS X. I'd like to know what is the deepest folder there is on my system (I don't care for access rights). This is because I want to launch a command on the root `/` and it will be recursive and I don't want it to hang (unexpected results). So I need to know how many levels of folders there are between `/` and the deepest folder.

I searched on Google and forums but couldn't find anything conclusive. I read that the HFS+ filesystem I'm using has no limit in depth, but maybe there is a limit in path name length ?

EDIT: Someone tried by [filling up the fs](http://martin-thoma.com/check-file-systems-maximum-path-depth/) but it's a dirty solution... I'd like a "cleaner" one if possible. Actually, finding the maximum depth on my actual system would be enough without testing out the limits.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Note that the linked post determines the deepest *possible* path. You seem to be asking for the longest actually existing path.

Comment: Yes, I'm asking for the longest actually existing path. That link was the only thing I found on Google that was approximately what I was searching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following traverses your entire file system looking for directories only, removes everything that's not a forward slash (path item delimiter), and prints the longest trail (at least on my system, sort behavior may depend on locale).

```
find / -type d | sed 's|[^/]||g' | sort | tail -n1
```

Count the resulting slashes, which is one for every directory except root, so if the deepest directory path were `/Users/danielbeck`, the result would be `//`. Of course, there could be files in that directory.

Comment: yeah. that's better. :-)

Comment: Great, I got `//////////////////////////` if anyone is interested (that's 26 folders deep).

Comment: also pipe the output to `wc` like so... `| wc -c` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Daniel Beck](https://superuser.com/users/22317/daniel-beck)'s answer but for those who like counting machines

`find / -type d | sed 's|[^/]||g' | sort | tail -n1 | egrep -i -o / | wc -l`

If the deepest directory path were `/Users/danielbeck`, the result would be `2`

Answer (score 1):

Finds the deepest path in a directory
tree using `find`'s starting-point as 0:

```
$ find / -type d -links 2 \
  -printf %d\\n | sort -nu | tail -n 1
```

Or you could use `%p` which will include
the
 starting-point, it allows you to specify
directories
 in your search and still start counting from `/`:

```
$ find /usr /lib -type d -links 2 \
  -printf %p\\n | awk -F / '{print NF-1}' | sort -nu | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score -1):

easiest way ?

```
mkdir /a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a
```

your deepest dir is now that.

less easy way ? Probably something like:

```
for i in `find .`; do echo $i | tr -d -c '/\n' | wc -m >> /tmp/counts; done; sort -nr /tmp/counts | head -n 1
```

i.e: show all file paths, rips out anything that isn't /. Count how many there were, then show the highest number.

something like that - feel free to improve it, pretty sure the /tmp file can be avoided using an in-memory file of some sort.

Comment: When I tried it, it somehow stopped after some time and went unresponsive... Thanks for the idea !

Comment: This will break if any path contains a space in its name. Don't parse the output of `find` or `ls`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Yeah, it sucks. I know. Personally I'd just do the mkdir and move onto the next problem.